# When should we define a function inside a React class as arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I'm creating a web page using React. There is a `textarea` where we could input a text. Thus, inside `return`, `onChange` is linked to a function named `inputChange`:

```
<textarea value={this.state.text} onChange=...></textarea>
```

Regarding `inputChange`, one way is to define it as a method (called `object method`?):

```
inputChange (event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState((s) => ({ ...s, text: value }));
}
```

Another way is to define it as an arrow function (called `class property`?):

```
inputChange = (event) => {
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState((s) => ({ ...s, text: value }));
}
```

(One thing I notice is that if we define `inputChange` as arrow function, we can see `inputChange` as a property of `this`, when we print `this` inside e.g., `render`.)

Does anyone know which way is be better? In general, when should we define a function inside a React class as arrow function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions come handy to tackle the problem of this in components. More often you would find yourself in situations when you are passing callback functions.

Now, in these cases not using an arrow function might cause issues because you ca not be sure of the value of **this** everytime the call back functions are called.

So a better approach is to use arrow functions instead. They preserve the value of **this** keyword inside the function as it was outside the function.

This approach resolves a lot of unseen frustrating bugs around which could arise due to incorrect usage and value of keyword **this**

For more detailed answers refer to [this](https://frontarm.com/james-k-nelson/when-to-use-arrow-functions/) article for explanation using code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to bind the inputChange function in order for it to receive the correct context and be able to use `this.setState`

Now you can bind it in multiple ways

First:

```
inputChange = (event) => {
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState((s) => ({ ...s, text: value }));
}
```

Second: Using bind in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.inputChange = this.inputChange.bind(this)
}

inputChange(event){
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState((s) => ({ ...s, text: value }));
}
```

Third: Inline bind or arrow functin

```
inputChange (event) {
  let value = event.target.value;
  this.setState((s) => ({ ...s, text: value }));
}
...
<textarea value={this.state.text} onChange={this.inputChange.bind(this)}></textarea>
```

or

```
<textarea value={this.state.text} onChange={(e) => this.inputChange(e)}></textarea>
```

Now you must note that when you bind the arrow function inline using the Third method, a new function reference is created on each render and it would have a very slight performance impact. However if you have many such functions returns, the performance impact will grow, not just because of more functions being created and a need for garbage collection, but because the child component optimization if any implemented using `PureComponent` or `React.memo` will start to fail as the function reference changes

**You can use any of the first or second approach for binding**

Comment: I understand we have several ways for binding to make it work. What I'm wondering is which defining of functions like `inputChange` makes more sense.

Comment: @SoftTimur I think I did mention it in my answer, you can use either or binding in function or defining function as an arrow function as both of them have similar performance. The least memory is used by using binding in constructor